# Check to see if row exists before adding it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a Certification process.  Right now it will add people to my Certification table even if they already are certified for the item in question.

On my view page, I have a `procedureID` and there Active Directory username.  I pass this to my controller method which then adds them to the table.

However if they already exist I don't need to add them just update the certification date and leave everything else alone.

What I am having trouble with is checking if they exist.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddCertification(int procedureID, FormCollection collection)
{
    string[] certifiedUsers = collection["members"].Split(',');

    IPACS_Certification ipacs_certification = new IPACS_Certification();

    foreach (var item in certifiedUsers)
    {
        // Does the certification exist?
        IPACS_Certification doesExist = db.IPACS_Certification.Where(m => m.adUserName == item && m.procedureID == procedureID).Select(m => m);
        ipacs_certification.procedureID = procedureID;
        ipacs_certification.certifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        ipacs_certification.adUserName = item;

        db.IPACS_Certification.Add(ipacs_certification);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("AddCertification");
}
```

My table contains the following columns.

certID (key IDENTITY)
procedureID (fkey to Procedure table)
certifiedDate DATETIME
adUserName NVARCHAR

If they exist I should be able to grab the row from the adUserName and procedureID and grab a unique single record.  If they do exist then all I need to do is update the certifiedDate to todays date.  If a record is not found then I need to perform the above add.

The above code has an error:

```
IPACS_Certification doesExist = db.IPACS_Certification.Where(m => m.adUserName == item && m.procedureID == procedureID).Select(m => m);
```

Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable to IPACS_Certification.  I know I am missing something there.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: what is the type of the "item" variable you are referencing?

Comment: @LukeW. only error I am getting currently is at the bottom of the original post.  The main question is I am unsure of how to check if a record exists without using an ID field.  Only have adUsername and procedureID to work with at this spot.

Comment: @CamBruce item is of type string which is taken from certifiedUsers, which is grabbed from the form collection.

Comment: Cool. Use FirstOrDefault() instead of Where(), as the answers below mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can check if the entry exist the following way:

```
bool exists = db.IPACS_Certification.FirstOrDefault(m => m.adUserName == item && m.procedureID == procedureID) != null;
```

if it does exist and you want to use the data from that row rather do it this way:

```
IPACS_Certification certification= db.IPACS_Certification.FirstOrDefault(m => m.adUserName == item && m.procedureID == procedureID);

if(certification != null) {
  // exists, do stuff with data from object
}
else {
  //doesn't exist, save the certification
}
```

Comment: I'm going to go with this one because it provides more info and fits with exactly what I needed.  Although all of the answers are correct and I appreciate them all. :)

Comment: For self-documentation purposes, I'd use `bool exists = db.IPACS_Certification.Any(...);` instead.

Comment: Yes or even db.IPACS_Certification.Where(m => m.adUserName == item && m.procedureID == procedureID).Any();

Comment: @AndrewCoonce thank you both I will update what I have with .Any() :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to select only one record :

```
IPACS_Certification doesExist = db.IPACS_Certification.Where(m => m.adUserName == item && m.procedureID == procedureID).Select(m => m).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `.Select(m => m)` that would return an `IEnumerable<T>`, you need `First`, or `FirstOrDefault`

So your query could be:

```
IPACS_Certification doesExist = 
  db.IPACS_Certification.FirstOrDefault(m => m.adUserName == item && m.procedureID == procedureID);
```

Or in your present query just add `FirstOrDefault()` at the end.

EDIT:

Or you can use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) with your current query like:

```
IPACS_Certification doesExist = db.IPACS_Certification
                                    .Where(m => m.adUserName == item && m.procedureID == procedureID)
                                    .Select(m => m);
if(doesExist.Any())
{
  //record exists
}
else
{
  // doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault to run your query and get back a single object.

```
IPACS_Certification doesExist = db.IPACS_Certification.Where(m => m.adUserName == item && m.procedureID == procedureID).Select(m => m).FirstOrDefault();
```